# Why tf.gradients doesn't work with integer constants?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Why the function below prints `None`?

```py
a = tf.constant(4)
b = tf.constant(2)

gr = tf.gradients(a + b, [a, b])

print(sess.run(gr))
```

But when I change

```py
-a = tf.constant(4)
-b = tf.constant(2)
+a = tf.constant(4.0)
+b = tf.constant(2.0)
```

It prints gradients. What is the reason for that?

Comment: When you say "It prints gradients" do you mean it literally outputs `gradients`?

Comment: @PranavA. it prints what is in "gr" variable

Answer (score 2):

According to https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20524 
tensorflow team made `tf.gradients` incompatible with integer tensors for this reason:

> In effect, allowing gradients on integer tensors was causing
>   incorrectness in tf.while_loop, and there was no satisfactory way to
>   resolve them without this change.

Comment: Note that, as the later comment in that thread points out, besides the technical complications it might cause, the concept of gradient does not really apply to integers. While one could say that, given an integer _x_, the gradient of 2 _x_ wrt _x_ is 2 (and that may work for many purposes), gradients are a fundamentally continuous construct (defined on the basis of limits), and reasoning about them in integer domain quickly falls apart.